# How to get PID of python3 working program

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, process, pid

I want to write a program on bash that will restart my script once every some time.
The program runs in an infinite loop and launch like this:

```
Python3 main.py
```

So to restart it, I need to do
`Kill [pid]` first and then restart it.
So how do I get the pid out? I used to do restarts manually, looking at the `ps -ef` list.
I tried to get `pidof python3` - it gives me 5 pid, which I don't like, because I can't really understand which one I need.
If I write something like `pidof "python3 main.py"` - it doesn't find anything.

[screenshot of process in ps -ef list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGgq2.png)

Test demonstration program:

```
#!/bin/python3
import time

x = 1
 
while True:
    print(x)
    x +=1
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods, in order of preference:

1. Use a service manager, such as systemd. The service manager takes care of tracking PIDs and you only tell it to restart a service by name, e.g.:

   ```
   systemctl --user restart MyScript
   ```
2. Have the script write its own PID to a "PID file", which you can then read using shell's `$(<file)`. The script can access its own PID via `os.getpid()`.

   ```
   kill $(< ~/myscript.pid)
   ```
3. Use the shell's `&` to run the script as a background job, which lets you access the PID as `$!` as soon as the job is spawned. You can then write the value of `$!` to a "PID file" (or immediately use it in a loop if you want).

Comment: 1. My program is not a service, so idk will it work or not. I tested it right now on demonstration program, got `Failed to restart main.py.service: Unit main.py.service not found.` I wouldn't ask if my program was a service.
2. Good idea! I will use this solution.
3. Cant figure out where i should put `&` in `python3 ./main.py`

Comment: The point here is to *make* it a service, preferably.